# Indeterminate form in $\lim \limits_{x\to 2}\left(\frac{g(x)}{f(x)-8}\right)^4$

Tags: calculus, limits

> PSQ: Suppose we know that $\lim \limits_{x\to 2}f(x)=8$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to 2}g(x)=-3$. Find each limit, breaking it down into steps that show how the limit laws apply.
>
> $$(a)\,\, \lim \limits_{x\to 2}\dfrac{3x\cdot f(x)}{g(x)-1}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(b)\,\,\lim \limits_{x\to 2}\left(\dfrac{g(x)}{f(x)-8}\right)^4$$

Having a difficult time understanding where to start with problem b.  My confusion comes from having no variable at all in the equation.  g(x) gets substituted with -3 and f(x) gets substituted with 8, giving us the limit as x->2 of (-3/8-8)^4, which gives us a zero in the denominator, making the problem an indeterminate form.  I typically would either rationalize or divide by the highest power, but that doesn't seem to work here with all constants.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you plug in the given information you get a nonzero number over 0.  Hint: this means that there are only 3 possible answers: $\infty$ , -$\infty$ , or DNE.  The power will narrow these down to the correct answer.

Comment: I'm just not familiar with this sort of form of a limit problem.  I assume with the power being even, both ends of the graph will point either upward or downward, (if it were odd, they would point in opposites), getting rid of the DNE option.  Then, since the final number is always positive as (x)^4 will always be positive, its probably going to end up being positive infinity?

Comment: Precisely! That is the right way to think about it.